# Node.js Client emit only after first time?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have a node.js server that Emits information to the client once it receives an email and password.  The only problem is that the emit only occurs once the SAME email and passwords are submitted. Here is my server code:

```
client.on('checkcred', function(email, password){
        helper.check(email, password,function(run){
        client.emit('conf',run);
        console.log(run);
                });
        });
```

helper.js

```
exports.check = function(zmail, pasword,callback){

                client.query('SELECT id FROM passwords WHERE email="'+zmail+'"', function(err,data){

               console.log("wrong email");
                callback("no");
                }else{
                        var savedemail = data[0].id;
                        client.query('SELECT password FROM passwords WHERE id='+savedemail+'', function(err,pass){
                                var databasepass = pass[0].password;

                                if (pasword == databasepass){
                                        console.log("correct pass");
                                        callback("yes");
                                }else{
                                        console.log("incorrectpass");
                                        callback("no");
                                }
                        });
                }

                });

}
```

Client:

```
  var socket  = io.connect('http://54.213.92.113:8080');

            socket.on('conf', function (yn) {
                    if(yn == "yes"){
                    window.location = "spec.html";
                    }else{
                    alert("Incorrect Email or Password");
                    }
                    });

 function upload(email, password){

            //check the email and password against the saved email and pass.
            socket.emit('checkcred', email, password);

        }
```

Here's the output...you can see where the output is 'wrongemail''no' the first time, there is no emit in between however, the second time, a function was emitted to the client!

```
   info  - transport end (socket end)
   debug - set close timeout for client Q7N-1qceSXBxORYXU4-y
   debug - cleared close timeout for client Q7N-1qceSXBxORYXU4-y
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client Q7N-1qceSXBxORYXU4-y
   debug - discarding transport
wrong email
no
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized CxnoJqQuGS3VwBP1U4-z
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/CxnoJqQuGS3VwBP1U4-z
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client CxnoJqQuGS3VwBP1U4-z
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
wrong email
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"conf","args":["no"]}
no
```

I have no idea why this is happening!

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce...OK, so I should store the email and password in a different way? What would you recommend?

Comment: You need to store a _hash_ of the password.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: Also, use booleans.  Also, users can easily bypass your security.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I'll look into bcrypt. I'm pretty new to password protections though. Would you be able to direct me to a good resource about how to do it correctly?

Comment: Here's some information on securely hashing passwords: http://jerryorr.blogspot.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-lots-of-donts.html It has a Java example, but the overall principals are the same with node.js/bycrpt.

Comment: I've implemented bcrypt...it's working well and now hides the passwords. However, my code still does not work on the first try!!! Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: Hashing passwords is the least of your problems when you still have that SQL injection problem out there.

Comment: @Brad Do you have any advice or resource recommendations about to solve that problem?

Comment: Use an existing framework like Passport.  Security is _hard_; do not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @pj409 Use prepared/parameterized queries any time you use arbitrary data in an SQL query.